# Storing Messages and Discussions in Messaging App Using Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, parse-platform, messaging

I am creating a messaging app for iOS using Parse as the backend and I am trying to come up with the schema for storing messages/discussions. Storing messages is straight-forward, but how have people been storing discussions, since a discussion involves a group of messages with one or more users and can be deleted as a whole. Is this just a clever query of the messages class, or an entire class on its own?

What does the typical schema look like for the Messages class and Discussions using Parse?

Thanks in advance for any help!

PS. Can anyone recommend any really good third-party libraries for making a messaging screen similar to Facebook Messenger.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Parse as your back-end, then the best feature for you is PFRelation. For your _User object, you can have a property of type PFRelation, with a target class of Discussions (custom class of yours, that you can call whatever you want). A Dicussions object within itself would probably have a property with an array of some sort, with people who are taking part in that discussion, with just their objectIds ("participants" maybe). And another property that holds an "array" of messages (this would technically be a PFRelation property, but if as the documentation will let you know, this is technically not an array). Therefore, to query for discussions the user is part of, you would do a query on the Discussions object class, whereKey:@"partcipants" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId

An important note is that you can easily remove/add objects from a PFRelation property, yet those objects are not already fetched, and you must first fetch the items in a PFRelation in order to access them. (You'll see this if you go to the documentation) It is for this reason that you have to fetch objects within a PFRelation before doing an actual query on them.

The reason that your array of users can just contain their objectIds, is to avoid the time it takes to actually fetch the objects in a PFRelation. Remember, when querying an array property the whereKey:equalTo: method checks whether the object next to equalTo: is contained within the array property.

Finally, you can have a "messages" PFRelation property that when accessed will take you to your Message objects that were submitted to a certain Discussion object.

Go look up PFRelations, they're your friends and are a way to tackle your problem with straight-forward queries.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... Good question. I've done it using the "clever query" method for one-to-one messaging, but I think it may make more sense to create separate classes dynamically in the case of group messaging, since in order to allow a flexible number of participants, you'll need to store them in an array; and querying a class for entries containing an object in an array is an especially time-intensive operation. So to find a user's specific conversation within one big messaging class could take a lot of time. I think it's better to use separate classes where each conversation has its own class.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Are you suggesting to have something like a Discussion class that contains and array of pointers to the Messages it contains, as well as the fromUser and toUser, etc.?

Comment: No, I was suggesting having the messages contained in the discussion class, but having pointers of each user's discussions attached to their user object. I don't see any point in separating the discussion class from the messages...